# Java File upload to MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob, r.java-file

I have this problem getting a `java.io.File` from the selection of a `JFileChooser` to upload the said `java.io.File` object to the MySQL Table having this table structure

```
     COL_NAME  COL_TYPE     ATTRIBUTES        EXTRA
(PK) idSample  int(10)      UNSIGNED ZEROFILL AUTO_INCREMENT
     FileName  varchar(250)
     FileBin   blob         BINARY
```

And from this Java code, the `newConnection` method is a static method of the class wherein it returns a new instance of a DriverManager default to the said MySQL Database. Another thing, I am using the `java.sql` package not the `com.mysql.jdbc` package.

```
public static boolean insert(final String filename, File file) throws SQLException, IOException {
    boolean flag = false;
    try {
        Connection connection = newConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(SQL_INSERT);
        statement.setString(1, filename);
        statement.setBlob(2, new FileInputStream(file), file.length());
        flag = statement.executeUpdate() > 0;
        statement.close();
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        throw ex;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return flag;
}
```

When I tried to run the program, it returns an error leading to the `statement.setBlob` line having this stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V
```

How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried using SetBinaryStream instead of SetBlob? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setBinaryStream(int, java.io.InputStream)

Comment: Still return the same exception.

Comment: The exception is telling you that the last parameter is a long (J). Try casting file.length to int:  ...., (int) file.length());

Comment: Read the byte data from the stream and use that as your argument to setBlob instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AbstractMethodError` means your JDBC driver's `PreparedStatement`s don't implement `setBlob(int, InputStream, long)`.

Use the older `setBlob(int, Blob)` or update your driver (Connector/J 5.1 implements Jdbc 4.0, which should be what you need for `setBlob(int, InputStream, long)`)