# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, blob

I am trying to save an uploaded file in MySQL database as follows:

```
String firstName = request.getParameter("firstName");
String lastName = request.getParameter("lastName");

InputStream inputStream = null; // input stream of the upload file

// obtains the upload file part in this multipart request
Part filePart = request.getPart("photo");
if (filePart != null) {
    // prints out some information for debugging
    System.out.println(filePart.getName());
    System.out.println(filePart.getSize());
    System.out.println(filePart.getContentType());

    // obtains input stream of the upload file
    inputStream = filePart.getInputStream();
}

Connection conn = null; // connection to the database
String message = null;  // message will be sent back to client

try {
    // connects to the database
    DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL, dbUser, dbPass);

    // constructs SQL statement
    String sql = "INSERT INTO image(image,firstName, lastName) values (?, ?, ?)";
    PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

    if (inputStream != null) {
        // fetches input stream of the upload file for the blob column
        statement.setBlob(1, inputStream);
    }

    statement.setString(2, firstName);
    statement.setString(3, lastName);

    // sends the statement to the database server
    int row = statement.executeUpdate();
    if (row > 0) {
        message = "File uploaded and saved into database";
    }
} catch (SQLException ex) {
    message = "ERROR: " + ex.getMessage();
    ex.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if (conn != null) {
        // closes the database connection
        try {
            conn.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    // sets the message in request scope
    request.setAttribute("Message", message);

    // forwards to the message page
    getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Message.jsp").forward(request, response);
}
```

When i run this i get an error which is:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception

root cause

java.lang.AbstractMethodError: com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBlob(ILjava/io/InputStream;)V
    UploadServlet.doPost(UploadServlet.java:64)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

what could be the reason of this error ?input field names are firstName,lastName and photo

Comment: Hey . How did you solve this problem as the answer here is also not working for me.

Comment: @Kanchan it's better if you save it in a folder and store path of that image in database

Answer (score 3):

You should use     `mysql-connector-java-5.1.7-bin.jar` to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

As stated by giorgiga in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13789797/java-file-upload-to-mysql) its your JDBC driver's version. Either update it or use the older version of setBlob.

**Edit:**
Taken from giorgiga's answer just in case link dies.

> AbstractMethodError means your JDBC driver's PreparedStatements don't implement setBlob(int, InputStream, long).
>
> Use the older setBlob(int, Blob) or update your driver (Connector/J 5.1 implements Jdbc 4.0, which should be what you need for setBlob(int, InputStream, long))

Comment: whats the older version of setBlob?

Comment: this is the older version i guess