# Hibernate - Blob

Tags: java, hibernate, blob

I try to update a table "image" in my DB and insert the blob type.

```
public static void main (String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException{
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory();
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
        File image = new File("c://img//button.png");   
        System.out.println("file esistente ? "+image.exists());
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(image);
        Blob blob = Hibernate.getLobCreator(session)    
                .createBlob(in, image.length());        
        Image imageClass = new Image();
        imageClass.setImage(blob);
        imageClass.setName("blobTry");
        session.save(imageClass);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        sessionFactory.close();
    }
```

imageclass:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name = "IMAGE")
public class Image {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "IMAGE")
    private Blob image;

        /* ... auto generated getters / setters */
    }
```

Hibernate User mapping:

```
 <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost/hibernatetutorial</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>

        <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size">0</property> 
        <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>

        <mapping class="com.journaldev.hibernate.model.Image" />
```

lib:

[image]

The error:

> Hibernate: insert into IMAGE (IMAGE, NAME) values (?, ?) Exception in
>   thread "main" java.lang.reflect.UndeclaredThrowableException  at
>   com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13.save(Unknown Source)   at
>   com.journaldev.hibernate.main.ImageTest.main(ImageTest.java:35) Caused
>   by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.hibernate.context.internal.ThreadLocalSessionContext$TransactionProtectionWrapper.invoke(ThreadLocalSessionContext.java:356)
>     ... 2 more Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError:
>   com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.setBinaryStream(ILjava/io/InputStream;J)V
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$5$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:151)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BlobTypeDescriptor$2$1.doBind(BlobTypeDescriptor.java:107)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:90)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:286)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:281)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.type.AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractSingleColumnStandardBasicType.java:56)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2843)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.dehydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2818)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister$4.bindValues(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3025)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.id.insert.AbstractReturningDelegate.performInsert(AbstractReturningDelegate.java:57)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3032)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3558)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityIdentityInsertAction.execute(EntityIdentityInsertAction.java:98)
>     at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:490)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addResolvedEntityInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:195)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addInsertAction(ActionQueue.java:179)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.addAction(ActionQueue.java:214)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.addInsertAction(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:324)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:288)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:194)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:209)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:55)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:194)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:49)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:90)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:715)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:707)    at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:702)     ... 7
>   more

Comment: Could you show us the User class?

Comment: Quick solution, try @Lob (it will guess the type, clob or blob)

Comment: add user class @Hichamov

Comment: Can you try changing the Blob data type to Byte[] data type?

Comment: i do it but the problem persist

Answer (score 1):

Taken the following answer from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13790674)

AbstractMethodError means your JDBC driver's PreparedStatements don't implement setBlob(int, InputStream, long).

Use the older setBlob(int, Blob) or update your driver (Connector/J 5.1 implements Jdbc 4.0, which should be what you need for setBlob(int, InputStream, long))

Comment: ERROR: could not execute statement; ( i do update my connector to a mysql... 5.1.18)

Comment: Then that is not a error related to the issue this post is speaks about. Your case must be with the statement you are trying to execute instead of the method itself.

Answer (score 0):

i change the type of data file into bean "image" Blob to byte[] and now it work